# Retrieve Selected value from the column of the table PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can i retrieve selected value of the 'level' column from the table VBmembers to set it as `$level` variable?

```
    session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $query = "SELECT level FROM VBmembers WHERE user='$user'";
    $level = queryMysql($query);
    $loggedin = TRUE;
}
else $loggedin = FALSE;
```

queryMysql function code

```
function queryMysql($query)
{
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('ivalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a couple of more steps, most importantly fetching the data in a usable way from the result:

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$query = "SELECT level FROM VBmembers WHERE user='$user'";
$result = queryMysql($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$level = $row['level'];
$loggedin = TRUE;
```

As I stated in comments, [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).